# Virtuemart: Echo order_number on order_done page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, virtuemart

Now in the page **views/cart/tmpl/order_done.php** there is `echo $this->html`. How can I echo order_number as single record? `$this->order_number` and `$order['details']['BT']->order_number` don't work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**order_done.php:**

```
require_once(JPATH_VM_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'models'.DS.'orders.php');
$order = VirtueMartModelOrders::getOrder($this->cart->virtuemart_order_id);
echo $order['details']['BT']->order_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just provide more information about the `$order` data ? Is it an Array or Object Or combination of Both ? If Possible print the whole order data value here ?

Comment: It seems [the combination of both](https://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=97449.msg339416#msg339416) but I'm not sure (please see the post of bolonia by the link). $html is being generating in another file